# Angular.js - $cookieStore null in promise callback

Tags: angularjs, promise, cookiestore

I'm trying to get my head around Angular.js and can't seem to resolve one problem that I'm having.

I have the following code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('authValidator',['ngCookies', 'ngResource']).factory('$authValidator', ['$cookieStore', '$http', function($cookieStore, $http){
return {
    setUserToken: function(token){
        $cookieStore.set('currentUserToken', token);
    },
    userToken: function(){
        $cookieStore.get('currentUserToken');
    },
    loggedIn: function(){
        return false;
    },
    requestAuthentication:function(username, password){
        var self = this;
        return $http.post('/login', {"username":username, "password":password}).then(function(response) {
            self.setUserToken(data.security_token);
        });
    },
    clearUserToken: function(){
        $cookieStore.remove('currentUserToken');
    }
}
}]);
```

The problem that I'm having is that $cookieStore appears to be null inside the 'then' and as a result I encounter this error:

```
Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$cookieStore.set('currentUserToken', token)')
```

I know there is an incredibly basic thing that I'm missing, but I can't seem to find it. Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that [`$cookieStore` has a `put`, but no `set`](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ngCookies.%24cookieStore).

Comment: Well isn't that a RTFM moment. Thanks John - much appreciated.